# Project war not created after running build all environments

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

MobileFirst Studio 6.3
Windows 7.

Used HellWorld sample to verify scenario.

Selecting Run As -> Build All Env   The project .war file is not created.  The only way it seems to generate the project .war file via "Run As" is to deploy the application to the test server. (Run As -> Run on MF Dev Server)

What is the appropriate approach in studio to cause the .war to be generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Build All command is related only to the .wlapp file(s).

Select "Run on MobileFirst Development Server" in order to actually have a runtime to run your application on.

Comment: @Adar, Can a `.war` file created by the MobileFirst Development Server (MFP studio) in the project `bin` folder directly be used in the production environment ?

Comment: Yes, you're supposed to take that .war file and deploy it to your production environment.